# Terminal autocomplete: cycle through suggestions

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I had this on my Ubuntu setup and since I switched to Fedora I want to set it and I forgot how... The idea is simple :

I don't want the terminal to show me suggestions when I double <kbd>tab</kbd>, instead I want it to cycle through every possible suggestion with each press on <kbd>tab</kbd>... this can be done in Vim also.

So when I type `gedit a` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> it will show me every file with a first letter `a`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is actually a readline feature called `menu-complete` . You can bind it to tab (replacing the default `complete`) by running:

```
bind TAB:menu-complete
```

You probably want to add that to your `~/.bashrc`. Alternatively, you could configure it for all readline completions (not just bash) in `~/.inputrc`.

You may also find `bind -p` (show current bindings, note that shows tab as `"\C-i"`) and `bind -l` (list all functions that can be bound) useful, as well as the [bash manual's line editing section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Line-Editing) and [readline's documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Documentation).

Comment: Can i combine 2 methods of autocompleting (the list and inline) and thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @vanjadjurdjevic: Sure, just bind them to different keys.

Comment: `menu-complete` is cool, but it hides the list of all possible suggestions ;-( Is it possible to both see the list and cycle through options?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩  I also like this feature in readline based shells. Currently the zsh way to do it is very cool: first hit of tab shows all possibilities, second hit of tab starts cycling the completion items.

Comment: @xuhdev Yeah, we shouldn't expect Bash to get those feature done anytime soon... but I'm too lazy too switch! Nice to hear from you xudev, fellow productivity addict :-)

Comment: Let's pretend you are using `cd` and `menu-complete` and cycling over directories. What key do you press to "pick" that directory and start cycling the contents of that directory? Is there another thing to set/bind?

Comment: @Tony forward slash works pretty well. Really any key does, as it resets where completion starts from. Not sure if there is another keybinding as well... Seems like that might make a good question here.

Comment: @derobert but the thing is, if I type forward slash (or another key), it will input that into my terminal and i have to delete it to continue cycling in that directory? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tony yeah, it'll insert it. But if you use forward slash, that's OK—a path like "`/usr/local//`" is still perfectly valid, and will start menu-completing things inside `/usr/local`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 I've added an answer that will give you this feature! :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447638/191530

Answer (score 13):

You can cycle through the completion menu in Bash, and you can also show the menu of items. Unlike in Zsh, the current menu item will not be highlighted.

Add to `~/.inputrc`:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set show-all-if-unmodified on
set menu-complete-display-prefix on
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

Documentation from `man bash`:

```
Readline Variables
    menu-complete-display-prefix (Off)
           If set to On, menu completion displays the common prefix of the
           list of possible completions (which may be empty) before cycling
           through the list.
    show-all-if-ambiguous (Off)
           This alters the default behavior of the completion functions. If
           set to On, words which have more than one possible completion
           cause the matches to be listed immediately instead of ringing
           the bell.
    show-all-if-unmodified (Off)
           This alters the default behavior of the completion functions in
           a fashion similar to show-all-if-ambiguous. If set to On, words
           which have more than one possible completion without any
           possible partial completion (the possible completions don't
           share a common prefix) cause the matches to be listed
           immediately instead of ringing the bell.

Completing
    menu-complete
          Similar to complete, but replaces the word to be completed with
          a single match from the list of possible completions. Repeated
          execution of menu-complete steps through the list of possible
          completions, inserting each match in turn. At the end of the list
          of completions, the bell is rung (subject to the setting of
          bell-style) and the original text is restored. An argument of
          n moves n positions forward in the list of matches; a negative
          argument may be used to move backward through the list. This
          command is intended to be bound to TAB, but is unbound by
          default.
    menu-complete-backward
          Identical to menu-complete, but moves backward through the list
          of possible completions, as if menu-complete had been given
          a negative argument. This command is unbound by default.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful when I have Unicode characters in the filename that I don't want to take the trouble to type.

Answer (score -1):

**Alternate solution through a new shell environment**:

I would recommend changing the terminal environment from bash to [fish](https://fishshell.com/) which comes with auto-completion by default along with syntax highlighting and several other features.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your post doesn't explain how to achieve the desired behavior as expressed in the question; you may want to add this to the description.